# NSArray does not accept NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, nsarray

In my application, I want the user to select a Contact with a peoplePicker. I then want to store the Record ID in an NSArray, so i have to convert it to a NSNumber. But when adding the NSNumber to the Array, it does not. There is no error, but when I look at the objects in the debugger I see, that the NSNumber `personId` has the right value, the array `personAdd` however does not contain it.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    NSNumber *personId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];
    NSString *first = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *last = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSArray *personAdd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, last, personId, nil];

    [self.myContactDataSource addPerson:personAdd]; //further usage of the data

    [self.tableView reloadData];                            //reload table view and
    [peoplePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  //dismiss people picker
    return NO; //tell peoplepicker not to display the contact details
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: So to clarify from your comments, none of first, last, or personId are nil at the time you declare personAdd?

Comment: How is myContactDataSource declared as a property (assign, retain, copy?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, assuming first, last and personId are all not nil . . .

You say it looks wrong in the debugger - how do you mean?

What happens if you do this - can you copy the console into your question :

```
// Debug the person id
NSLog(@"%i", [personId intValue]);

// Check that it's in the array OK
NSLog(@"%i", [personAdd objectAtIndex:2]);

// Add it to your stuff
[self.myContactDataSource addPerson:personAdd];

// Check that the array is still OK
NSLog(@"%i", [[myContactDataSource objectAtIndex:2] intValue]);
```

I know it's not quite an answer but it might shed some more light on the problem!

Comment: Ok, with these I got it right, and the answer makes me feel somewhat confused ... it seems like the debugger is not capable of displaying NSNumbers values while theyre inside an array, whyever this might be so ... (self.myContactDataSource is retain btw but with custom getter with lazy initialisation)

Comment: Hah - thought it might just have been the debugger! Try setting a breakpoint on the last NSLog and trying this `po [personId intValue]` and `po myContactDataSource` in the console - it's much more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if first or last is nil?

```
NSArray *personAdd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, last, personId, nil];
```

The arrayWithObjects method stops at the first nil it sees - if first or last are nil then it will never add the personId :(

Comment: first and last both contain valid strings and the debugger shows them inside the array, so this can not cause the error

Comment: Don't always trust what the debugger displays. "Print description" will be correct most of the time.

Comment: isn't the 'Print description' menu option _exactly_ the same as `po myObject`?